# R ggplot geom_tile x axis year quarter labeling

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some time series data with quarterly frequency, as below.

I'm using `geom_tile` to create a heatmap of these time series data, but the issue I have now is that the labeling on the x axis is defaulted to year eventhough the data is on quarterly.

My expectation was something like `2014 Q1`, `2020 Q4` as in the dataset.

```
set.seed(1990)
ID <- rep(c('A','B','C'),each = 84)
n <- rep(round(runif(84,1,4)), 3)
datetime <- rep(seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2020-12-01"), by="month"), 3)
df <- tibble(ID,n, datetime)
df <- df %>% 
  #mutate(yearweek = tsibble::yearweek(datetime)) %>%
  mutate(yearquarter = zoo::as.yearqtr(datetime)) %>%
  #group_by(ID, yearweek) %>%
  group_by(ID, yearquarter) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(n))
df
ggplot(df
       ,
       aes(y=ID,x= yearquarter,fill=n))+
  geom_tile(color = 'gray')
```

[image]

Normally I can easily control the monthly level dataset with `scale_x_date` as below but using it with quarterly data throws `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`.

I'm using `tsibble::yearweek` to get weekly aggregation and `zoo::as.yearqtr` for quarterly aggregation.
But the issue is when it comes to plotting, `ggplot` may not support them. So is there a more consistent approach to dealing with time series data with multiple frequencies in `R`/`ggplot`?

```
scale_x_date(expand = c(0,0),breaks = seq(as.Date("2014-07-01"), as.Date("2020-12-01"), by = "1 month"), date_labels = "%Y %b", name = 'Monthly')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `zoo`'s `as.yearqtr` variable use `zoo`'s `scale_x_yearqtr` to format the x-axis.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df,aes(y=ID,x= yearquarter,fill=n))+
  geom_tile(color = 'gray') +
  zoo::scale_x_yearqtr(format = '%Y Q%q')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ronak! Would you happen to know for yearweek?

Comment: There is no `yearweek` function. If you keep your data in `POSIXct` class then you can use `scale_x_datetime` with `date_labels = '%Y %W'`